# ASP.NET display one message for multiple validators

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

Let me start by stating what I am really trying to do: I have to check a field for multiple "exclusive" (I'll explain) criteria, and display a single validation message.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" CssClass="field"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Text="Amount is required"/>
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency" Text="Amount must be numeric"/>
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ValueToCompare="10" Type="Currency" Text="Minimum donation $10.00"/>
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="LessThan" ValueToCompare="10000" Type="Currency" Text="Wow that's too much"/>
```

I have left off some tags for readability - all validators are in the same validation group, they have ID's, `ControlToValidate="Amount" Display="Dynamic"`.

If the Amount field is blank, or has a number in it, all is fine. However, if I put text in the field:
[image]

Even though the <10, >10,000 and DataTypeCheck should be exclusive, the numeric comparisons fail on the string.

I realize I could use a `CustomValidator` for this, but I would like to eventually style one the messages differently, in its own separate `<span>` element.

So, my incorrect (because they aren't "What am I really trying to do?") questions are:

1. How do I make a `CompareValidator` of currency type not fail on text? *or*
2. How do I display only the first message from multiple validators? *or*
3. How do I do what I want to do?

Comment: Looks like CustomValidator is your best option after all. Is the only thing that stops you is a difference in appearance of one message - it can be easily figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using a `CustomValidator` and setting a label where I wanted my different message.

.aspx page:

```
<span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" CssClass="field"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator [same as earlier...] />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="AmountCustomValidator" ControlToValidate="Amount" ValidateEmptyText="False" OnServerValidate="AmountCustomValidator_ServerValidate"/>
</span>
<span>
    <asp:Label ID="AmountTooMuchMessage" runat="server" Text="" />
</span>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void AmountCustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = true;
    AmountTooMuchMessage.Text = ""; //Reset special error label text

    decimal amountFormatted;

    if (!decimal.TryParse(args.Value, out amountFormatted))
    {
        AmountCustomValidator.Text = "Amount must be numeric";
        args.IsValid = false;
        return; //Don't try to compare values to non-numeric input
    }

    //This is money, so make it two decimals
    amountFormatted = Math.Round(amountFormatted, 2);
    Amount.Text = amountFormatted.ToString();

    if (amountFormatted < 10)
    {
        AmountCustomValidator.Text = "Minimum donation $10.00";
        args.IsValid = false;
    }

    if (amountFormatted > 10000)
    {
        AmountCustomValidator.Text = "";
        AmountTooMuchMessage.Text = "That's too much";
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Note that I had to remove the `ErrorMessage` tag on the `CustomValidator`, otherwise it will show when `Text=""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function(event) {
    // Allow only backspace and delete
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.keyCode > 48 || event.keyCode < 57 ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
```

});

Also, if you are using HTML5 you could simply use

**EDIT 1** corrected the comparison operator to allow digits 0-9.

Comment: <input type="number">

Comment: I tried adding `type="number"`, but the browser ends up styling it with its own styling (spin counter, red glowing border for invalid)

Comment: I consider this more of a workaround, but it does work. I have to leave the validator for DataTypeCheck, since there are always ways around this. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/995183/3271599) has a bit more detailing on the keyCode's to include.